# Java and Node.js lovechild to exe

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I'm currently coding a project in Java that will use external JavaScript files to read and analyze local files (and thus, also using Node.js for RequireJS). I usually use an application that allows me to package multiple jars (such as libraries) with the main project jar into a .exe for easy distribution, but I'm realizing that this will be significantly more difficult with the JavaScript involved.

Does anyone know how I could convert my .js files into one (or more) .jar files such that I'd be able to reference them in Java and include them in my .exe?

(I'm aware that this may not be possible, but I've seen enough things while researching this that make it seem like it might be possible that I figured it was worth asking)

Comment: Out of interest, why js & java at the same time?

Comment: nope not possible to convert to jar, but you can use other techniques, for example executable archive.

Comment: You can certainly package them in jars as resources, the same way you would, say, an image. Then you'd either have to rely on nodejs being installed on the target system (and some configuration pointing to it, maybe), or ideally run them with Nashorn.

Comment: @Marc I'm making a game board and want to have essentially plugin rules, such that I can pass them a representation of the board in its current state and get a boolean back saying if it passes. I don't know how to make plugins in Java, especially easy to make and add ones, but I do know how to iterate through all the .js files in a folder and run a process(json) command from them. The JS that would need to be packaged with the main file would read an initial gameboard state from a .json